# Android HttpDefaultClient times out only after another device makes a similar but not identical request

Tags: android, httpclient

Some quick background. We have multiple devices running a scanner app which checks against a database to see whether an id has been scanned in or not. I can scan in with Device A as many times as I like without issue. I then pick up Device B and scan in, also as many or few times as I like. If I pick Device A back up and scan, the HttpClient will hang for approximately 60 seconds refusing to send any further requests. The code below has commented the point of failure.

```
// Asynchronous get request
private class aGETRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String response = "";
        for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            client.setKeepAliveStrategy(null);
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet); //Hangs Here
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(httpEntity.getContent());
                BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(isr);

                String s = "";
                while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                    response += s;
                }

                httpEntity.consumeContent();
                isr.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            httpGet.abort();
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
        return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        results(result);
    }
}
```

The client hangs and even snooping traffic shows no requests sent at all from Device A after the failure. You ready for the best part? If the devices are going through a Proxy server, it works. W.T.F?

Comment: did you try to execute your requests with another client ? (something as simple as curl for instance)

Comment: Oh absolutely, we could hit the server with curl every time without delay during this test, it appears to be completely device (Motorola TC55 running Android 4.1.2) related.

Answer (score 0):

Android is java 6 compat . right.

BufferedReader on java 7 makes me nervous and the while read loop appears to be whats hanging.....

I would try a different different read loop class thats solid on java 6 or i would find someone else's pattern for httpclient that's solid.

My wild guess is that your code is never getting out of the following...

```
while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null)
```

Maybe the server is returing chunked encoding or something like that with a diff protocol ( pattern of length=0 followed by \r\n or [something](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding#Format).